# How to set the value of a void **

Tags: c, void-pointers, sbrk

So I am trying to use the following code to add some memory to the heap without using malloc (size is a unsigned int parameter in the function, and is not a set number)

```
void * temp = sbrk(sizeof(void*)+sizeof(unsigned int)+size);
```

Now I want to set the value of the void * in temp to be NULL, however when I try to do

```
*(void *)temp = NULL;
```

my compiler tells me that I cannot dereference a void *.  How do I solve this error?

Comment: Try `*(void **)temp = NULL;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the value of `temp`, use `temp=NULL`.

If you want to put `NULL` in the address that `temp` points to, use `*(void**)temp=NULL`.

Comment: Solved it perfectly.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `temp` as a `void*`, not a `void**`.

If it were declared as a `void**` then `*temp = NULL` would work.